# PS script to login into salesforce.com

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to write a powershell script to simply log into salesforce.com.  From there I'll just find some resulting HTML to find out if it was successful or not.  This is what I have so far.

```
$username = "myusername" 
$password = "mypassword"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://login.salesforce.com")

$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= "$username"
$ie.document.getElementById("pw").value = "$password"
$ie.document.getElementById("Login").Click()
```

The problem I have is that when I execute the click method nothing happens.  Since the form is visible I can see that the username and password fields are set correctly.  Just nothing happens when I execute Click.

I didn't past the code from the site but you can view source at https://login.salesforce.com

Anyone have any ideas why click isn't working.  Wasn't sure if it's because of the type of button, or the onclick method using javascript, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow. Your script is very similar to the one found here : http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/69eaa0bc-c0fc-4948-bd4c-6dab8d85179e

```
$username = "myusername" 
$password = "mypassword"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://login.salesforce.com")
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; 
} 
$ie.document.getElementById("username").value= "$username"
$ie.document.getElementById("pw").value = "$password"
$login = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("button") | ? {$_.id -eq "Login"}
$login.click()
```

The way  to get it working is almost identical, but unlike googles page, saleforce uses the `id=Login` in many places, and if you run `$ie.document.getElementById("Login")` you can see that `tagName : DIV`... In order to get the login button, I just started by getting all the buttons, and then finding the one with the Login ID

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The code makes sense, and I had tried something similar in the past, but it doesn't work either.  I get an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Comment: @user3416569 That happens when you leave out the while loop that checks if the explorer is still loading, and then sleeps for 1 second until the browser is ready. It works though I've tested it on V2 and V4

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.  I even copied this block and put it into a script file and ran it from the powershell prompt.  Same null-valued expression error.  Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, I put in a bunch of echo statements and the error comes right after the click statement, so not related to the navigate

Comment: @user3416569 Idk what to tell you man, I've tested it on XP with V2 and IE8 and Win7 with v4 and IE10 ... You literally just copy that block of code, change username and password and run it. Maybe add a `sleep 1` before `$login.click()` although you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, it definitely helped.  I was able to get something different to run.  It's the getElementsByTagName that failed with the parameters we have.  I ran that (without the extra filtering - that gives me too much data) and iterated in a foreach loop until it found one with a tagname of button.  From there I the click works.  Perhaps it's because it's on a server with IE9, or that server has some other security settings that are preventing this from running correctly.